# User Study Setup: Correct selection of tasks

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, experiment-design

I'm struggling with the problem to design a formally correct user study.
I have the following circumstances:

- I want users to assess the (subjective) usefulness of a -so called- trail result. That means particularly that I want to test trails for (amongst others) their "usefulness" (dependent parameter).
- Trails (or if you want configurations) are defined by two independent parameters

  (1) a data item and (2) an processing algorithm.
- I have around 2000 trails resulting from the power-set of the (all data items $ \times$ processing algorithms)
- The goal of the user study is to find out that a certain algorithm works better than another algorithm on all data items (more users rated the result as useful). Specifically, I want to derive a ranking that says: "This algorithm is in average better/more useful than another algorithm".

I see here a three dimensional optimization problem for selecting the trials for each participant:

1. I want the best coverage over all trails
2. I need a good/significant coverage among the algorithms. Otherwise the is not significant. (I need redundancy/overlap in the trails)
3. I need to vary the data items, since their characteristics affect directly the usefulness of the algorithm outcome.

The question is now how do I select the trails for each participant?